# problema con ajax en navegador chrome

Tags: ajax

Describo mi problema. Estoy haciendo ejemplo simple con ajax. Tengo por una parte el html con un botón donde al hacer click debería mostrar un mensaje "este es un mensaje utilizando ajax" (el cual está en un txt) .

Primero me daba un error del tipo XMLHttpRequest cannot load "ruta del archivo". Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

El cual he podido encontrar una solución :

Cuando intento ejecutar un código Ajax dentro de un html en local con Chrome, el código Ajax no se ejecuta por seguridad . El error que me da la consola en Chrome es: XMLHttpRequest cannot load "ruta del archivo". Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

La solución más acertada es deshabilitar esa seguridad para poder ejecutar Ajax, para ello primero cierro Chrome, ya que si hay alguna ventana abierta no funciona.

Luego accedo a la consola y escribir la ruta de Chrome seguido de los siguientes parametros, en el caso de windows es:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

Al hacer esto me abre una ventana de Chrome y ahí podremos introducir la url local y funcionará Ajax sin problemas. Una vez cierro todas las ventanas de Chrome se deshabilitará de nuevo esta opción, por lo que deberíamos volver a repetir estas acciones para poder hacerlo de nuevo.

Hasta ahí todo correcto. Una vez hecho esto el navegador me da el siguiente error al ejecutar el código: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

EL cual no se como solucionar. Imagino que será muy sencillo pero no se como llegar a la solución.

Mi código fuente es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Definición HTML5 del documento -->
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

</head>
    <style type="text/css">  

    <

<body>

<button onclick="ejecutarAJAX()">Hazme Click</button>
<div id="info"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ejecutarAJAX()
    {
        var ajaxRequest;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ //navegadores tipo chrome
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{ //navegadores antiguos (ie)
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        //0 Petición no ha sido inicializada
        //1 Petición no ha sido establecida
        //2 Petición no ha sido enviada
        //3 Petición esta siendo procesada
        //4 Petición ha sido finalizada

        var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }

        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "documento.txt", true);
        ajaxRequest.send();

    }
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que documento.txt está en la misma ruta que tu fichero html?

Comment: prueba con la ruta absoluta del archivo. por ej: c:\documentos\documento.txt (o el directorio donde lo tengas)

Comment: Si, está en el mismo directorio que el html. Poniendo la ruta absoluta del fichero me da el mismo error

Comment: Parece ser que este problema suele producirse porque no estas corriendo la aplicación en un servidor web. ¿Es ese tu caso? Si es así, prueba a meterlo en un apache o un iis a ver que sucede.

Comment: Lo estoy corriendo en local. He probado a abrirlo una vez abiertos los servicios apache y mysql. El error que me da es: Failed to load : (ruta del fichero). Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.